# Load another app from current application

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter, android-package-managers

Hi I am developing an android app where I am displaying all the installed apps on a list view . On click of the list item, I am trying to open that particular app.

This is the code i am trying

```
    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
    {
        private Intent intent;

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int position, long arg3) 
        {

                String packName = (String) listOfapps.get(position).get("packagename");

                intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packName);

                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
                startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

This works fine for some apps. But on click of Contacts and few apps, I am getting force close as

android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.android.contacts/com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Not sure where I am going wrong.
 Please Help. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that there are packages that don't provide a launcher `Intent` that you can use. To prevent your app from crashing, you should be able to test if your launcher `Intent` will actually work by doing this:

```
String packName = (String) listOfapps.get(position).get("packagename");
intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packName);
// See how the package manager will resolve this Intent
ResolveInfo resolveInfo = getPackageManager().resolveActivity(intent,
            PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
// Only start the activity if the package manager can resolve the Intent
if (resolveInfo != null) {
    startActivity(intent);
} else {
    // Tell the user he can't launch this app or whatever
}
```

You also don't need to set `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` or `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED` on the `Intent` because those flags should already be set for you by the call to `getLaunchIntentForPackage()`.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
try
{
    String packageName = "APP_PACKAGENAME";
    Intent launchIntent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
    startActivity(launchIntent);
}
catch (Exception e1)
{
}
```

Where package name is the name of package of another application you want to start

Comment: Gee, that's exactly what OP is already doing. Why do you think this answer is any improvement on that?

Answer (score 0):

For opening Contacts and some internal apps you need to call intents.
for ex. for **Contacts**. you can try this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
```

You can give **if** clause to the **mListView.setOnItemClickListener** to some apps which are internal.

Hope this helps.!!